# Wordpress - Featured image on a custom post archive page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

i have created a custom post named Products.

```
register_post_type( 'products',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Products' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
        ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' )
);
```

I have also created a php file named **archive-products.php** and made it into a template.

In Wordpress I have created a page named **Products** and selected the products template.

On that static page (that uses the archive template) I have uploaded a image into the Featured Image panel.

In my header I have the code:

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail();
```

But this echos the Featured image of the **last custom post** in the list (all the products posts have a featured image as well), not the Featured image of the static/archive page, which is what i want. Is this possible to achieve?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did the very same thing and came across the following answer that solved my problem: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/175228

1. Save your custom post type archive template as a page.

   For example, page-products.php
2. Backup locally and delete your custom post type archive template from your server.
3. Show the image with `the_post_thumbnail()`, put it in a variable with `get_the_post_thumbnail()`, or make it a background image with your page title over it:

   `$bg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $page->ID ), 'full' );
   if( is_page('products') ) : ?>
     <div style="background: url('<?php echo $bg[0]; ?>') repeat center center #fbfbfb; background-size:cover;">
       <?php the_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
     </div>
   <?php endif; ?>`
4. Save your permalinks and refresh your page.

This is what worked for me. Hope it helps somebody. :)